# why the swap func didnt work for me?

Tags: java

i start learn java, and i build 'swap' function that replaces numbers.

when i run this code, its not replace them.

how could i solve this problem?

```
public static void swap(double i, double j){
        double temp = i;
        i = j;
        j = temp;
}
```

this in the main:

```
double i = 1;
double j = 2;
System.out.println(i+" - "+ j);
swap(i, j);
System.out.println(i+" - "+ j);
```

---

in the Console i see:

```
1.0 - 2.0
1.0 - 2.0
```

and i need to see:

```
1.0 - 2.0
2.0 - 1.0
```

Comment: Java is pass by value.

Comment: Oh God, not this again. Abandon thread!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: That statement means nothing to a Java neophyte.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sure, but it's a keyword that they can look up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, everything is passed by value, including primitive types.  You have copies of `i` and `j` in your `swap` method.  You did swap the values `i` and `j`, but only the local values `i` and `j` in the scope of your `swap` method.  The `i` and `j` in `main` were not changed.

To swap the values, implement the swap code inline in the `main` method, not in a separate method.

Answer (score 1):

Java is pass by value, even for references.  You are changing a copy of the original values, not the originals.

There is no way to implement a swap method in Java to do what you suggest.